# Html/Css how to change the background color of the favicon

Tags: favicon

I have a website favicon or head tag:

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}" style="background-color: rgba(0, 56, 103, .94) !important;">
</head>
```

This will display here:
[image]

My question is, how can I change the background color of this favicon.

I have tried to add css to it, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define a favicon with a `link` tag. This tag doesn't accept style and can't be changed via CSS. You'll have to change the icon itself.

You can learn more about the `link` tag at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link.